# Generate a list of template-instances and call a static function on them

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, c++17

Say I have a set of templates `template<int N> A{}` and `template<int N> B{}` and so on with template `C`, `D` .... They all have a static member function `init()`.

I would like to write a metafunction generating `A<0>`, `B<1>`, `C<2>` and so on. Lets name this variadic metafunction `SeqInst`. And this metafuntion has also a static memberfunction `init()` which in turn calls all `A<0>::init()`, `B<1>::init()`and so on.

I tried to write `SeqInst` as variadoc template, then instantiate `SeqInst<A, B, C>` and to use this to form a parameter list for another template `Initializer`: 
so inside of `SeqInst`I like to use:

```
template<typename... T>
struct Initializer {
    static void init() {(T::init(), ...);}
};
```

After all it should look like:

```
using si = SeqInst<A,B,C>;
si::init();
```

This should in the end call `A<0>::init()` and `B<1>::init()` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence). We just make a sequence of the right size, and use that to call `init()` while folding over a comma:

```
template <template <int> class... Z>
struct SeqInst {
    static void init() {
        init(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Z)>{});
    }

private:
    template <size_t... Is>
    static void init(std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
        (Z<Is>::init(), ...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Would it be possible to instantiate a nested variadic class template with the parameters `A<0>`, `B<1>` and so on?